# How can I play audio at the end of my python pygame project?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a connect four game and I have implemented a sound effect of dropping a chip using `pygame.mixer.Sound.play` to play a short .mp3 file.

However, once the game is over, I cannot get the .mp3 file to play that I would like to use then.  The pygame screen closes and the program exits successfully.

My main.py has a "while not game_over" loop.  And I attempted to play the song after that loop exited and a player had won, but that was unsuccessful, I also attempted to use sleep to stop the program from exiting but that also failed.  I would like to put the command to play the music in my winCheck function like below, but as I previously stated the program just exits and the song does not play.

Any help would be appreciated, my attempt to add it to a winCheck function is shown below:

```py
if count >= 4:
    win = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/win.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(win)
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the music to finish playing:

```py
win = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/win.mp3")
win.play()
while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    pygame.event.poll()
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue.  My only question is what does pygame.event.poll() do at the end of this loop?  What event is it getting?

Comment: @J From the documentation  [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump): *"For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system."*

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `time.sleep` or to use `pygame.mixer.get_busy()` to wait till your Sound/Music has finished playing. My choice would be something like this:`while pygame.mixer.get_busy() == 1: time.sleep(1)`